# To find the JIRA Query to find no of tickets assigned

Tags: jira

How to know the JIRA query for**strong text** tickets assigned on someone in JIRA on a particular day?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% of what you are asking but if you are inquiring on the JQL to determine what issues were assigned to user `Bob` last `Thursday` where some may no longer be assigned to him this is not possible without a use of some sort of plugin. (Which may or may not exist)

For tickets currently assigned to Bob that is:

```
assignee = Bob
```

You can read more about [Advanced Searching here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA063/Advanced+Searching).